# Am I setting up a Pricebook Entry incorrectly?

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

Update with More Code:

The Test Class contains:

```
        Product2 plc = new Product2(Name='My Product', ProductCode='PC-1');
        insert plc;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        PricebookEntry PLCpbe = new PricebookEntry(Product2Id=plc.id, UnitPrice = 200, Pricebook2Id=pricebookid, isActive = True);
        insert PLCpbe;

        Order ord = TestDataUtility.addorder('Test Order',ac.id,'Draft',con.id,null);
        ord.Pricebook2Id = pricebookid;
```

// This may have been my issue! This pricebookID was different than the one assigned to my Pricebook Entry. I'm getting new errors now, and will continue troubleshooting, but is this likely the issue?
            insert ord;

---

In my trigger code, I query for a PricebookEntry by ProductCode. Everything works great when I actually use it in the Test Org. and I'm creating a Test Class now, which is what I'm having an issue with.

The error I get is : INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

So I'm hoping somebody can review how I'm setting up a Product, Pricebook, and Pricebook Entry in a Test Class, and setting PBE to an OrderItem in case I'm doing something wrong.

In my Test class, I create a Product

```
Product2 plc = new Product2(Name='My Product', ProductCode='PC-1');
    insert plc;
```

I get a pricebook ID with

```
ID PricebookID = Test.getStandardPricebokID();
```

Then...

```
PricebookEntry PLCpbe = new PricebookEntry(Product2Id=plc.id, UnitPrice = 200, Pricebook2Id=pricebookid, isActive = True);
insert PLCpbe;
```

---

So, in my actual code, I query for a PricebookEntry by the product code and get a proper ID (not null, that is).

And try to create an OrderItem

```
OrderItem plcLineItem = New OrderItem(OrderId = o.id, PricebookEntryId = plcpbe.ID, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 200);
```

Like I said, this all works perfectly fine in actuality, but when I run my test class with this test data, I get the following error on upsert* of the OrderItem

INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

I've researched this and it seems, to my understanding, that this error means an ID was set to a field incorrectly, as in, it's not the right kind of ID somehow.

- I upsert because in my code, I'm inserting some varying number of OrderItems, and updating others in some cases, so I add them all to a List and upsert all at once at the end.

Can somebody help identify where this error is coming from? I can't think of why an ID would be improper in this case. Let me know if you need any more information - thanks!

Comment: Did you insert the order before creating the line items? Perhaps OrderId is actually null?

Comment: Mhm! I actually printed out the Order ID and the whole OrderItem to see it's values - no null values, the IDs make sense to me, so I figure I've got to be setting something up wrong. But yes, Order ID is not null, and I print out the PBE ID throughout the process, and it is what is assigned to the OrderItem. Stumped!

Comment: And the Order wouldn't be null because this is a trigger on Order :) So the top-level process is...I insert Order, change something about it (description), update it, and the trigger created the Oitems etc...

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: @SantanuBoral there is a lot of other code not related to this part in the trigger code. I tried to pull the related pieces. What other components might help?

Comment: Can you `System.debug()` all of the Ids you're populating in that OrderItem and show their values here?

Comment: Hi @DavidReed - I debug the ID of the Pricebook Entry (when queried, and right before upsert), and it is :  01u1k0000017nMEAAY

Before upsert, I debug the whole order item. It is : {OrderId=8011k0000004KeIAAU, PricebookEntryId=01u1k0000017nMEAAY, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=200}

Comment: The error (in original question) occurs on the upsert specifically

Comment: If you split out the upsert into an insert and an update just for the sake of discussion, does the behavior change or is it isolated to one specific DML operation?

Comment: In my test class, upsert is not necessary, so I am able to insert for the sake of testing! Unfortunately, same issue

Comment: I know you said there's a lot of code involved, but can you try to isolate a minimal example that shows this behavior? I'd love to be able to drop it in my developer org and troubleshoot.

Comment: @DavidReed I think the mistake was that the Order Pricebook ID was a different one than was assigned to the Pricebook Entry. Now I'm getting SOQL Limit reached errors, but not the error I got before. I think that may have been it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error was in the Pricebook Entry ID on the Order - it was not the same as the one on the Order Item Pricebook Entry. When I changed this, I no longer got the error

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting because the error message is rather inscrutable, so I put together a minimal example to demonstrate Natalie's analysis of the mistake. Here's a simple test class. We create two Orders, one with the test context's standard pricebook and one with a new pricebook. We then run a `goodTest()`, where we add an `OrderItem` a pricebook entry in the *same* pricebook as its Order, and a `badTest()`, where the `OrderItem` has a pricebook entry in a different pricebook.

Lastly, we run an `otherGoodTest()` where we insert an `OrderItem` on the non-standard Pricebook, but use a PricebookEntry that's also in that pricebook.

As predicted, `goodTest()` and `otherGoodTest()` pass and `badTest()` fails, confirming that this error stems solely from the mismatch in pricebooks.

```
@isTest
public class OrderTestTest {
    @testSetup
    public static void testSetup() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        insert a;

        Product2 plc = new Product2(Name='My Product', ProductCode='PC-1');
        insert plc;

        PricebookEntry PLCpbe = new PricebookEntry(Product2Id = plc.id, UnitPrice = 200, Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), isActive = True);
        insert PLCpbe;

        Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Pricebook');
        insert pb;

        Order ord = new Order(Name = 'Bad Order', AccountId = a.Id, EffectiveDate = Date.today(), Status = 'Draft', Pricebook2Id = pb.Id);
        insert ord;

        ord = new Order(Name = 'Good Order', AccountId = a.Id, EffectiveDate = Date.today(), Status = 'Draft', Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId());
        insert ord;

    }

    @isTest
    public static void badTest() {
        Order ord = [SELECT Id FROM Order WHERE Name = 'Bad Order'];
        PricebookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry];

        OrderItem plcLineItem = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.ID, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 200);

        insert plcLineItem;
    }

    @isTest
    public static void goodTest() {
        Order ord = [SELECT Id FROM Order WHERE Name = 'Good Order'];
        PricebookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry];

        OrderItem plcLineItem = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.ID, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 200);

        insert plcLineItem;
    }

    @isTest
    public static void otherGoodTest() {
        Order ord = [SELECT Id FROM Order WHERE Name = 'Bad Order'];
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
            Product2Id = [SELECT Id FROM Product2].Id, 
            UnitPrice = 300, 
            Pricebook2Id = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name = 'Pricebook'].Id,
            isActive = True
        );
        insert pbe;

        OrderItem plcLineItem = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.ID, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 300);

        insert plcLineItem;
    }
}
```